# How to do CSS ul li fade out the text?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a vertical a menu, but menü text will appear on mouse hover. But text will appear left side of item.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><span>İtem-1</span></li>
    <li><span>Long Name İtem-1</span></li>
    <li><span>Very Long Name İtem-1</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and css is:

```
.container{
  margin: auto 50%;
}
ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;  
}
 ul li{
    position:relative;
    background:#E01B6A; 
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
ul li span{
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover span{
     position: absolute;
     display:  inline-block;
     background:#fefefe;
}
```

Text will appear in a square when Mouse hover.

[TEST page](https://jsfiddle.net/L6htypsb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the text to appear outside of the square. To do so, set the `left` or `right` properties to position the text:

```css
.container {
  margin: auto 50%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  background: #E01B6A;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li span {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover span {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fefefe;
  right: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><span>İtem-1</span></li>
    <li><span>Long Name İtem-1</span></li>
    <li><span>Very Long Name İtem-1</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Same thing actually.

Comment: Ok thanks, can you set vertically center of the box?

Comment: Yep - set the line-height to the box height.

Comment: is it possible to set an icon center of the red box?